# Show dependencies of global variables in C code

Tags: c, variables, dependencies, extern

I'm analysing an existing C code project which uses global variables a lot (extern keyword). My problem is that the keyword is not only used in the .h files of the depending variable but also in other .c files wherever there is need to access a variable.

Is there a tool which allows me to select a variable and see all the accesses across the project (selection of .c files)?

I know that there is the possibility to use the search function every time but I'm dealing with around 400 extern keywords so I won't do anything else than searching.

Comment: `grep`, or some combination of `find` and `grep` should work.

Comment: cscope is a useful tool as well.

Comment: Alot of IDE's also have a "find usage" function that works ...for all of Eclipse's faults, this is one of the things it does pretty well. (Of course, getting it into the IDE is probably impossible at this point).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' `grep -rnw 'srcdir' -e "VARNAME"`

Comment: @ Grep users: Yeah that's possible but i dont want to do it like 400 times... That's why I'm looking for something more interactive like an IDE plugin or a dedicated program for this.

Comment: A bit more comfortable than grep and integrated within eclipse: rightlick a variable -> Open call hierarchy. This shows all the accesses of this variable for the whole project (excluding the declarations, very nice for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Eclipse:
rightlick a variable -> Open call hierarchy

This shows all the accesses of this variable for the whole project (excluding the declarations)

I will keep my eyes open for a feature like this listing all the variables of a module.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the real computer scientists and command line zealots.. I cheat with GUIs... If you use IDEs like Xcode, you should be able to click on the var while pressing `cmd` or `Ctrl`, it'll take you to the declaration of the symbol. Most IDEs allow you to search the project (i.e. all files), that's how I find where a var is used sometimes. [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is a great tool if your code is well documented. Run it recursively in you project dir and take a look at the html output, which shows you all the global vars and cross references.

Comment: I'm also kind of a fan of GUI applications, but thats another discussion.

I'm using Eclipse and I know about this feature to search for delecations and/or usage. But this doesn't suit my needs in this case. I'm trying to understand the code (kind of reverse engineering) and I want to get an overview. Btw: Its not documented :-(

Comment: @Burner yeah I totally understand your pain! I was in the same situation two months ago.. had to take over multiple big projects written in C, all of which poorly documented. I had to do a lot of searches in these source files which was time consuming, and a big challenge for a lazy person like me :P but I'm glad a I did it because I got to understand the code better and establish docs for Doxygen. I also learned some cool programming tricks. Definitely a greater gain in the long run.